# How to access a variable which is defined in the main thread?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a program. In `main()` it creates two thread thread_A and thread_B.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        pthread_t thread_A, thread_B;
        volatile int label; // share with thread_A and thread_B

        pthread_create(&thread_A, NULL, thread_A_Main, NULL);
        pthread_create(&thread_B, NULL, thread_B_Main, NULL);

        // other codes ...
}
```

`thread_A_Main` and  `thread_B_Main` are in other files. Now I want to access `label` in thread_A and thread_B, the method below does not work:

```
extern volatile int label;
void *thread_A_Main(void *) 
{
    // some codes ...
    label++;
    // some other codes ...
}
```

when compiling, I was told `thread_a_main.c:(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to label`.
What is the right method to share a varible between the main thread and other created thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make it a global by declaring it *outside* of main.

```
volatile int g_label; // global

int main() {
    // ...
}
```

When you put `label` *inside* of `main()` like you have, that variable is *local* to `main`, which usually means it lives on the stack of `main` (temporary storage).

By moving it to the outside, we've put it in the data section, which is stored along side the actual program text, in an area of memory accessible by the entire process.

Comment: couldn't he also extern it if i'm not mistaken?

Comment: @Ion The `extern volatile int g_label;` will *still* be needed in the other C files he's compiling. (It should actually be in a header).  `extern` only tells the compiler: "Hey, don't expect to find this symbol in this module... it's somewhere else. Let the linker take care of it at the end".

Comment: Sure his idea of "defined in the main thread" makes sense here. The variable he originally comes into life inside the `main` function  and is local to that execution. This function is executed in a specific thread, compared to two other threads he is creating. The two he is creating have no visibility of the local variables from the execution of `main`, a whole new "stack" is created with them.

Comment: @JensGustedt You're absolutely correct. It was a half-thought through statement that I should have left out. I was simply worried that he assumed that there was a 1:1 function:thread relationship.

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare it as a **non-static** global variable in a source file (**not in a header file**).
2. "Extern" it anywhere you want to use it, or simply in one header file and then include this file.
3. You will probably have to treat it as a critical section and protect it with some OS resource (mutex, semaphore, etc), in order to ensure a mutually-exclusive access to this variable by different threads.

Answer (score 0):

label in your case is stored in the main thread stack which means that it is not accesible in your other threads.
You can try to make label global.